# Remove dock icon for shell executable in Mac OS X?

Tags: python, macos, dock, cx-freeze

I know you can remove the dock icon for an app by setting `LSUIELEMENT = 1`. I have an executable created by `cx_freeze`, which bundles a set of Python scripts into a single executable. How can I remove the dock icon, with or without using AppleScript?

Answer (score 0):

Ordinary executables (i.e. command line tools) do not show up in the dock.

Comment: I m using the executable binary created with cxfreeze(python scripts to executable)

Comment: @makalways: you should probably mention that in your question and clarify what you mean by "executable" - I'm guessing that cxfreeze actually produces a bundle rather than a plain executable.

Answer (score 0):

My app has some helper command-line tools in one of its frameworks. If the tools are stored in the framework’s executable directory, Mac OS X wants to show them in the Dock. Since the tools run quickly, this appears as a brief flash where all the other Dock icons move to make space for the new icon and then move back.

To fix this, I am setting `LSBackgroundOnly` to `true` in the `Info.plist`. `LSUIElement` would probably also work. Since a command-line tool is just a single file, the way that you set the `Info.plist` is to have a separate file that Xcode embeds in the binary. You can set this by adding  `-sectcreate __TEXT __info_plist $(INFOPLIST_FILE)` to the `OTHER_LDFLAGS` build setting. (Hopefully there is a Makefile line or equivalent where you can set this for `cx_freeze`.)